# Is the property of definite integrals: $\int_a^b [f(x)+g(x) ]\:dx = \int_a^b f(x)dx + \int_a^b g(x)dx$ still valid when one of they diverges?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

For example:

\begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty \left( \frac{1}{\ln x}+\frac{1}{1-x} \right)dx = \gamma\\
\end{align*}
where $\gamma$ is the Euler–Mascheroni constant.
The both integrals below are divergent:
\begin{align*}
&\int_0^\infty  \frac{1}{\ln x}dx \\
&\int_0^\infty  \frac{1}{1-x}dx.
\end{align*}

Can I still write:
$$\int_0^\infty \left( \frac{1}{\ln x}+\frac{1}{1-x} \right)dx = 
\int_0^\infty  \frac{1}{\ln x}dx + \int_0^\infty  \frac{1}{1-x}dx$$
and manipulate each integral on the right side the way I want? For example, doing substitutions etc.

Comment: Each of the integral is diverges but when you subtract one of another, it's not. For example $\lim_{n \to \infty} n = \infty $ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{n^2 + 1} = \infty $, but $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{n^2 + 1} - n   = 0$

Comment: In $\int_a^b [f(x)+g(x) ]\:dx = \int_a^b f(x)dx + \int_a^b g(x)dx$, if two of the three integrals converge, then so does the third and that equation holds.  As noted in another comment, if one of the integrals diverges, then the equation may fail.